# Plaintext POP3 client using C in Linux - error reading after sending command to server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client, pop3

I've been trying to write a `POP3`   client for yahoo, but whenever I send a valid command, I cannot read from `socket` . I know it's not safe to create applications that deal in `plaintext`  over the web, but I'm just trying to learn more about `POP3`  for now.

I'm creating a graphic interface using `QT` , but I believe this is irrelevant for now.

First of all, I made sure that yahoo supports `plaintext`  communication by running simple commands in the terminal:

```
telnet pop.mail.yahoo.com 110
+OK hello from popgate-0.8.0.504347 pop011.mail.ir2.yahoo.com 
user validuser
+OK password required.
pass validpassword
+OK maildrop ready, 100 messages (134513 octets) (13531)
```

This is how I handle opening the connection:

```
int openConnection(char ip[], int port)
{
//descriptor of socket
int sd;

struct sockaddr_in server;


//fill in server structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (ip);
server.sin_port = htons (port);

//create communication socket
if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        //if cannot create, return error
        return -2;
    }

if (connect (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
    return -1;
  }

return sd;

//values to be returned
//-2 - could not create socket
//-1 - could not connect to server
//socket descriptor in case of success
}
```

I get no problem with creating the socket and connecting when I call

```
int sd = openConnection ("188.125.68.106", 110)
```

(188.125.68.106 = ip of pop.mail.yahoo.com)

I can even read the welcoming message without using select or epoll.

```
char message[80];
read (sd, message, 80);
```

Message:

```
+OK hello from popgate-0.8.0.504347 pop011.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
```

I can also send all sorts of invalid commands, and read the error returned

```
int sd = openConnection ("188.125.68.106", 110)
write (sd,"this command is invalid",80);
char messageFromS [80];
bzero (messageFromS, 80);
read (sd,messageFromS,80);
```

And I get something between the lines of

```
-ERR invalid command
```

But whenever I send a valid command, my client just freezes up after calling read and I have to force quit

```
write (sd,"user validuser",80);
char messageFromS [80];
bzero (messageFromS, 80);
read (sd,messageFromS,80);
```

Afterwards, I decided to use  `select()`   because I know it's a good practice, and maybe it could give good results

```
//function returns true (1) if we can read from the socket
bool isClosed(int sock)
{
fd_set rfd;
FD_ZERO(&rfd);
FD_SET(sock, &rfd);
timeval tv;

//timeout value is set to 5 seconds
tv.tv_sec = 5;

select(sock+1, &rfd, 0, 0, &tv);
if (!FD_ISSET(sock, &rfd))
    return false;
int n = 0;
ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &n);
return n == 0;
}
```

But it seems that whenever I call

```
isClosed(sd)
```

It always returns True.

This is the point where I cannot think of any other options. Is there anything that Telnet has that my miniature client doesn't ?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers.
I played around with reading all the messages received byte by byte, until it found a termination character (apparently it wasn't NULL), and, after re-reading the RFC for pop3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1081) closely I realized that I wasn't ending my commands properly. I should have appended '\r' and '\n' to the end of all commands sent.
I also checked the select () command, which returned -1 and set the tv.tv_usec = 0 which pretty much solved it.

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for read()/write() and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity. If you do not know the amount of data to be received, read it byte by byte.

Comment: You should check the return value from `select`. I'll bet it's `-1` and with `errno` set to `EINVAL`. The reason I think so is because you don't initialize the `tv` structure properly. The `tv_usec` member will be a random value, and one that is probably illegal.

Comment: Oh, and you should of course check for errors from *all* functions that can fail. And don't check `errno` unless a function actually fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
I played around with reading all the messages received byte by byte, until it found a termination character (apparently it wasn't NULL), and, after re-reading the RFC for pop3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1081) closely I realized that I wasn't ending my commands properly. I should have appended '\r' and '\n' to the end of all commands sent.
I also checked the select () command, which returned -1 and set the tv.tv_usec = 0 which pretty much solved it.

– Shoshinsha purogurama